# 'display': 'block" div is appearing on all buttons(classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the display property of the div to block using jQuery when the button is clicked but since I have multiple buttons the div is appearing on each button.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-
hidden="true"></i></button>

<div class="dropdown-opt"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.btn-dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown-opt').css({'display': 'block'})
});
}
```

All I want is that the div appears only on the button which gets clicked and not on all the buttons. I think the concept of 'this' will help but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Is there a `div` for each `button`?

Comment: Yes there's a div for each button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just select the div [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to it

```
$('.btn-dropdown').on('click', function() {
   $(this).next('.dropdown-opt').css({'display': 'block'})
});
}
```

From docs of next()

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Comment: Had to edit my code a bit so as to make the div a sibling of the button but it worked. Thanks.